# Building high volume batch data processing tool in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, etl

I am trying to build an ETL tool using Java. ETL tools are for doing batch read, write, update operations on high volume of data (both relational and other kind). I am finding it difficult to choose right framework/tool to accomplish this task.

**A simplified Typical Use Case:**

1. Establish a connection with a database (source)
2. Read 1 million records joining two tables
3. Establish a connection with another database (target)
4. Update/write those 1 million records in the target database

**My Choices:**

1. Use plain JDBC. Build a higher level API using JDBC to accomplish the tasks of connecting, reading and writing data to and from databases.
2. Use some framework like Spring or Hibernate. I have never used these frameworks. I think Hibernate is for ORM purposes, but mine not a ORM kind of requirement. Spring may have some batch processing things but I wonder whether the effort to learn that is actually less than doing it myself as in my option 1.
3. Any other option/ framework?

*which one among above is best suited for me?*

**Considerations**

1. I need to choose an option that can give me high level of performance. I won't mind complexity or losing flexibility in favor of more performance.
2. I don't already know any of the frameworks like Spring etc. I only know core Java.

Of late, I have done lot of googling but will appreciate if you can provide me some "first hand" opinion.

Comment: This question is *far* too broad for a site like Stack Overflow. In addition to being underspecified (how many total records? what sort of throughput is needed? what sorts of transforms are happening), this is asking for high-level design advice, not help with a specific programming issue.

Comment: Yes I agree that it's broad. But Idon't agree that it's *underspecified*. Do you *really* want me to specify *how many total records*?

Comment: Order of magnitude? Sure. There's an important difference between a million records once and hundreds of millions per hour.

Comment: Ok, since it's a batch processing environment to be used for future clients, let's say the volume could be as high as 500M records per day and as low as 1000 records per month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on you usage scenario I would recommend [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html). It is very easy to learn and implement. On high level it contains the following 3 important components.

1. **ItemReader**: This component is used the read batch data from source. You have ready to use implementations like JDBCITeamReader, HibernateItemReader etc.
2. **Item Processor**: This component is used to write the JAVA code which will do some processing if needed. If no processing is needed this can be skipped.
3. **Item Writer**: This component is used to write the data to target in batches. Even for this component you have ready to use implementations similar to ItemReader.

Comment: This sounds really interesting... Do I need to know Spring framework first to use this?

Comment: @hashbrown You'd really want to know the basics of how the core framework works. You probably want to know it anyway; I use it for any non-toy Java application.

Comment: I see... but do you think it would worth the effort learning these frameworks viz-a-viz writing a targeted framework all by myself?

Comment: I feel every effort spent to learn spring modules is worth your time. IF you do not learn you would have to implement a similar design for processing. Learning spring will help you in future to leverage the code which is ready to use rather than "reinventing the wheel"

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the updates related to Spring Batch. However, after some research I have decided to use EasyBatch. From https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch,

> Easy Batch is a framework that aims to simplify batch processing with
>   Java. It's main goal is to take care of the boilerplate code for
>   tedious tasks such as reading, filtering, parsing and validating input
>   data and to let you concentrate on your batch processing business
>   logic.

Comment: FWIW I recommend EasyBatch to those who don't know Spring in advance, the learning curve is steep for Spring Batch.

Comment: @ hashbrown, @whitfin: Hi, I'm planning to use easy-batch too for one of our implementations. Just wanted to know your experience about it and how scalable it was with the implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Data Pipeline](https://northconcepts.com/), a lightweight ETL engine for Java.  It's easy and simple to use.